# Jackson ignore fields when writing

Tags: java, jackson

I'm reading this object from JSON using the Jackson library:

```
{
    a = "1";
    b = "2";
    c = "3";
}
```

I'm parsing this by using `mapper.readValue(new JsonFactory().createJsonParser(json), MyClass.class);`

Now I want to print the object to JSON, using `mapper.writeValueAsString(object)`, but I want to ignore the 'c' field. How can I achieve this? Adding `@JsonIgnore` to the field would prevent the field from being set while parsing, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do this by using public fields, you have to use methods (getter/setter). With Jackson 1.x, you simply need to add `@JsonIgnore` to the getter method and a setter method with no annotation, it'll work. Jackson 2.x, annotation resolution was reworked and you will need to put `@JsonIgnore` on the getter AND `@JsonProperty` on the setter.

```
public static class Foo {
    public String a = "1";
    public String b = "2";
    private String c = "3";

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getC() { return c; }

    @JsonProperty // only necessary with Jackson 2.x
    public String setC(String c) { this.c = c; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"c"})` while serializing the object.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"c"})
public static class Foo {
    public String a = "1";
    public String b = "2";
    public String c = "3";
}

//Testing
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.a = "1";
foo.b = "2";
foo.c = "3";
String out = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
Foo f = mapper.readValue(out, Foo.class);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that ignore the field when deserializing?