# How to tell to Jackson ObjectWriter ignore from class member during write

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Java.

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass{
    @JsonProperty("test")
    String test;

    String myPrivateTest;
}
```

I'm using `Jackson ObjectWriter` to write my JSON object to file/as string as follow:

```
ObjectWriter writer = objMapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
writer.writeValue(new File(path), myObject);
```

I want to write to file only `test` member and not myPrivateTest, How can I do it?

**EDIT**

I have been tried with:

```
class MyClass{
        @JsonProperty("test")
        String test;

        @JsonIgnore
        String myPrivateTest;
    }
```

And with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"myPrivateTest"})
class MyClass{
    @JsonProperty("test")
    String test;

    String myPrivateTest;
}
```

And It is still write myPrivateTest to the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson ignore fields when writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287811/jackson-ignore-fields-when-writing)

Comment: @gtgaxiola see my edit

Comment: which version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: veresion 1.9.13

Comment: I just tried your code with Jackson version 2.9.6 (latest) and it works just fine. You should look at updating your APIS (many things have been fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Jackson 2.9.6](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9)

Just adding the `@JsonProperty` to the fields you want is enough.

```
public class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("test")
    String test;

    String myPrivateTest;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.test = "HELLO";
        c.myPrivateTest = "WORLD";
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(c));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"test":"HELLO"}
```

`String myPrivateTest` is correctly ignored

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore specific fields with providing PropertyFilter as below :

```
@JsonFilter("someFilter")
@Data // lombok
@NoArgsConstructor // lombok
class SomeClass {
    private String name;
    private int someField;

    public SomeClass(String name, int sf){ 
        this.name=name;
        this.someField = sf;
    }
}

@Test
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass("test",1);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        PropertyFilter theFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
            @Override
            public void serializeAsField
                    (Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
                    throws Exception {
                if (include(writer)) {
                    // here you can define the properties to ignore
                    if (!writer.getName().equals("name")) {
                        writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) {
                    writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                }
            }
        };

        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("someFilter", theFilter);

        String objAsString = mapper
                .writer(filters)
                .writeValueAsString(someClass);

        assertThat(objAsString).doesNotContain("name");
    }
```

Serialized output is :

```
{"someField":1}
```